# Conditional statements in Tensorflow Dataset API

Tags: tensorflow

I've build a data pipeline using Tensorflow Dataset API but I would like some operations (like shuffling) to depend on whether I'm iterating over training or testing dataset. I'm wondering if there is a way to use conditional statements in the dataset API pipeline? I've tried the following code but it says it can't convert object of type `ShuffleDataset` to Tensor.

```
# This is the placeholder I feed with proper file name depending on whether I'm training or testing
filenames_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.string, shape = (None), name = 'filenames_placeholder')

# This it the placeholder I would like to feed with True/False to influence shuffling
shuffle = tf.placeholder(tf.bool, shape = (None), name = 'shuffle')

dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(self.filenames_placeholder)
dataset = dataset.map(lambda x: parse(x), num_parallel_calls = 4)

# The following does not work
def shuffle_true():
    return dataset.shuffle(buffer_size = 1024)
def shuffle_false():
    return dataset
dataset = tf.cond(self.shuffle, shuffle_true, shuffle_false)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just define a function

```
def tr_input_fn(filename, mode):
    dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filename)
    if mode == 'Train':
        dataset = dataset.shuffle()
        dataset = dataset.map(map_func)
        return dataset
    return dataset
```

As far as I know, there's now explicit conditional statements in dataset api.
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset